# Mutating Table in Oracle 11 caused by a function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

We've recently upgraded from Oracle 10 to Oracle 11.2.  After upgrading, I started seeing a mutating table error caused by a function rather than a trigger (which I've never come across before).  It's old code that worked in prior versions of Oracle.

Here's a scenario that will cause the error:

```
create table mutate (
    x NUMBER,
    y NUMBER
);

insert into mutate (x, y)
values (1,2);

insert into mutate (x, y)
values (3,4);
```

I've created two rows.  Now, I'll double my rows by calling this statement:

```
insert into mutate (x, y)
select x + 1, y + 1 
from mutate;
```

This isn't strictly necessary to duplicate the error, but it helps with my demonstration later.  So the contents of the table now look like this:

```
X,Y
1,2
3,4
2,3
4,5
```

All is well.  Now for the fun part:

```
create or replace function mutate_count
return PLS_INTEGER
is
    v_dummy PLS_INTEGER;
begin
    select count(*) 
    into v_dummy
    from mutate;

    return v_dummy;
end mutate_count;
/
```

I've created a function to query my table and return a count.  Now, I'll combine that with an INSERT statement:

```
insert into mutate (x, y)
select x + 2, y + 2
from mutate
where mutate_count() = 4;
```

The result?  This error:

```
ORA-04091: table MUTATE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "MUTATE_COUNT", line 6
```

So I know what causes the error, but I am curious as to the *why*.  Isn't Oracle performing the SELECT, retrieving the result set, and *then* performing a bulk insert of those results?  I would only expect a mutating table error if records were already being inserted before the query finished.  But if Oracle did that, wouldn't the earlier statement:

```
insert into mutate (x, y)
select x + 1, y + 1 
from mutate;
```

start an infinite loop?

UPDATE:

Through Jeffrey's link I found this in [the Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/intro.htm):

> By default, Oracle guarantees statement-level read consistency. The
>   set of data returned by a single query is consistent with respect to a
>   single point in time.

There's also a comment from the author in [his post](http://harmfultriggers.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/look-mom-mutating-table-error-without.html):

> One could argue why Oracle doesn't ensure this 'statement-level read
>   consistency' for repeated function calls that appear inside a SQL
>   statement. It could be considered a bug as far as I'm concerned. But
>   this is the way it currently works.

Am I correct in assuming that this behavior has changed between Oracle versions 10 and 11?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly,

```
insert into mutate (x, y)
select x + 1, y + 1 
from mutate;
```

Does not start an infinite loop, because the query will not see the data that was inserted - only data that existed as of the start of the statement. The new rows will only be visible to subsequent statements.

[This](http://harmfultriggers.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/look-mom-mutating-table-error-without.html) explains it quite well:

> When Oracle steps out of the SQL-engine that's currently executing the
>   update statement, and invokes the function, then this function -- just
>   like an after row update trigger would -- sees the intermediate states
>   of EMP as they exist during execution of the update statement. This
>   implies that the return value of our function invocations heavily
>   depend on the order in which the rows happen to be updated.

Comment: Good link, thanks!  I'm going to update my question and leave it open for a bit to see if it generates any additional discussion.

Comment: This helped, but have clarification question... Can the function exist in a Package that is called from a before update trigger? I am having a nightmare of problems like many others due to Oracles crappy triggers.

Comment: @RichBianco, in this context there's no difference between a schema-level function and a function defined in a package. The same behaviour applies when called from SQL.

Answer (score 8):

**Statement-Level Read Consistency and Transaction-Level Read Consistency".**

From the manual:

> "If a SELECT list contains a function, then the database applies
> statement-level read consistency at the **statement level for SQL run
> within the PL/SQL function code**, **rather than at the parent SQL
> level**. For example, a function could access a table whose data is
> changed and committed by another user. **For each execution of the
> SELECT in the function, a new read consistent snapshot is
> established"**.

Both concepts are explained in the "Oracle® Database Concepts" :

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/consist.htm#sthref1955

---

->>> **UPDATE**

->>>*Section **added after** the **OP was closed**

**The rule**

The technical rule , well linked by Mr Kemp(@jeffrey-kemp) and well explained by Toon Koppelaars [***here***](http://harmfultriggers.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/look-mom-mutating-table-error-without.html), is reported in "Pl/Sql language reference - **Controlling Side Effects of PL/SQL Subprograms**"(your function  violates **RNDS** reads no database state):

> When invoked from an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement, the function
> cannot query or modify any database tables modified by that statement.
>
> If a function either queries or modifies a table, and a DML statement
> on that table invokes the function, then ORA-04091 (mutating-table
> error) occurs.

[*PL/SQL Functions that SQL Statements Can Invoke*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#CHDJJCEC)

Comment: Good to know!  That seems like a another good reason to avoid function calls within SQL statements as much as possible, beyond the performance consideration - they violate the parent SQL level snapshot rule.

Comment: @Dan-A. I use them to simplify complex calculations upon row values in deterministic functions where they don't violate WNDS and RNDS (write no data state and read no data state).