# Trigger update joint view with trigger table

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm trying to get my trigger to update a view that joins two table one of which is the table that activates the trigger causing this error

> ```
> INSERT INTO MC_CLUB_MBR_TRANSACTION
>             *
> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-04091: table ESP8339.MC_CLUB_MBR_TRANSACTION is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
> ORA-06512: at "ESP8339.TRG_MC_UPD_DUES", line 2
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ESP8339.TRG_MC_UPD_DUES'
> ```

Here is the code I'm using

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_MC_UPD_DUES
 AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON 
 MC_CLUB_MBR_TRANSACTION
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE MC_TRAN_V
    SET MC_TRAN_V.DUES_DUE = (MC_TRAN_V.ANNUAL_DUES - 
    MC_TRAN_V.DUES_PAID_TO_DATE);
END;
/

INSERT INTO MC_CLUB_MBR_TRANSACTION
(
CLUB_CODE,
STUDENT_ID,
DUES_PAID_TO_DATE
)
VALUES
(
777,
20010,
300
);
```

Comment: you cannot update a complex trigger unless instead of trigger is used!!!

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+ORA-04091)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ora-04091 table is Mutating-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150671/ora-04091-table-is-mutating)