# Oracle - "table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it" error on update a table with no trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am getting this error: "**ORA-04091: table FASHIONRETAILER.Payslips is mutating, trigger/function may not see it**" on when trying to update on Payslips table, which has no triggers in it. The screenshot is attached proving there is no trigger on the table. Below is my update statement:

```
UPDATE "Payslips" 
SET "NETPAY" = calculate_net_pay(user_id)
WHERE "PAYSLIPSID" = (
    SELECT "Payslips"."PAYSLIPSID" FROM "Payslips" 
    WHERE "Payslips"."USERID" = user_id AND "Payslips"."Date" = (
        SELECT MAX("Payslips"."Date") FROM "Payslips" WHERE "Payslips"."USERID" = user_id 
        AND "Payslips"."NETPAY" IS NULL));
```

The `calculate_net_pay(user_id)` function and the sub-query in WHERE constraint are working properly.

[image: No triggers on Payslips table]

Comment: How is your function implemented? The error message is saying that the cause could be a function, not only a trigger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mutating Table in Oracle 11 caused by a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935239/mutating-table-in-oracle-11-caused-by-a-function)

Comment: My condolences on having to work with a data model where a table named `"Payslips"` has a column named `"Date"`. (btw you only have to double-quote items with non-standard naming.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `pragma autonomous_transaction` in the declare section of your function.
I don't see what `calculate_net_pay()` function exactly do. Therefore may be that is not the best solution for your case but it should work.
More about autonomous transactions see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00609)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot query the same table you are updating in a function or a trigger - your function calculate_net_pay does just that, it tries to calculate net pay for a user by querying table Payslips which you are trying to update.

Try using subquery instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve the problem and do what you want?

```
UPDATE "Payslips"  p
SET "NETPAY" = calculate_net_pay(p.user_id)
WHERE p."Date" = (SELECT MAX(p2."Date")
                  FROM "Payslips" p2
                  WHERE p2."USERID" = p."USERID" AND
                        p2."NETPAY" IS NULL
                 );
```