# How to find which trigger cause "(04091) Mutating Table Error in Oracle"

Tags: oracle, plsql

An update statement cause this:

> [Error] Execution (1: 1): ORA-04091: table BV_OWN.TABLE_TEST_QUERY is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
> ORA-06512: at "BV_OWN.PKG_TEST_LIBRARY", line 161
> ORA-06512: at line 3

According to
https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/mutating-table-error-in-oracle/
the cause would be a trigger.
But this table (BV_OWN.TABLE_TEST_QUERY) has no trigger.

Is there a way to select the trigger which cause this error?

Comment: Are you sure that TABLE_TEST_QUERY has no triggers? How did you check that? If you use GUI, did you refresh its contents? If you ran some SELECT statement, which one was it?

Comment: @littlefoot  I know that because I've created this table. And 

select * from all_triggers where table_name = 'TABLE_TEST_QUERY' gives no results

Comment: OK. Did you then check PKG_TEST_LIBRARY at line #161? What's in there? Maybe that piece of code is modifying another table whose trigger checks TABLE_TEST_QUERY which has also been affected in that transaction? What does `select * from user_source where lower(text) like '%table_test_query%'` return? Any trigger in that result set?

Comment: Yes I've check it. in line 161. it's doing that: execute immediate get_dynamic_query into variable.  This dynamic query has access to TABLE_TEST_QUERY, but it makes no modifications

Comment: select * from user_source where lower(text) like '%table_test_query%' returns only a function that insertthe value in TABLE_TEST_QUERY. But it's not used anywhere in the code. (only by me in a 'command line'). I've checked that in user_source. (2 lines: definition in spec and in body)

Comment: A FUNCTION inserts value into the table? Why? Functions (normally, if used in a SELECT statement) can't even perform DML. So I presume that you have something like `l_val := function_name; ` in your code. Maybe that's what causes the error? How about performing DML in a **procedure**, and let function do what it's designed for - return some value?

Comment: I'm not using the function to make a select. And no this function is not used in the software. It used only to insert the value in my table. In a short script not in the software.(declare; begin; use this function; end; I have said function but it's a procedure.

Comment: @Pierre-olivierGendraud check the error. It says "trigger/function" might not see it. A mutating table error can also be caused by a function which is probably what is happening in your case. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935239/mutating-table-in-oracle-11-caused-by-a-function . You'll have to debug that package (line 161). That is where your error is happening.